# Any chance to update a movie with AVfoundation without copying (like updateMovieFile in QTKit)?

Tags: macos, cocoa, metadata, avfoundation, movie

I recently used AVFoundation to add metadata to movies in my OS X 10.7+ app. Since my target is ARC (64 bit),  QTKit.framework and Quicktime.framework won't work. In this scenario I HAVE to write a temporal movie using AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough and then replace the source file with it.

However, Apple rejected my app arguing that it writes data out of allowed folders (my app receives movie files to add metadata through drag and drop so I don't know where is going to save). **How can I then replace the original movie with the updated metadata movie without an updateMovieFile method?.**

Is there anything similar in 64 bit land?. Any workaround?. Any advice?.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

QTKit ***is*** 64-bit-compliant and can be used. The use of ARC or not has no bearing on existing frameworks because the runtime is the same for ARC and MRC apps. ARC is a preprocessor and compiler step only, it does not require a special runtime, unlike Garbage Collection.

To save a file to any folder, if your app is sandboxed the way to do this is to use the PowerBox, which is a separate process that controls and displays the Open and Save dialog boxes. The PowerBox is used automatically if a sandboxed app requests an `NSOpenPanel` or `NSSavePanel`.

The way this would work is that when the user drags a file onto your app, your app would display an `NSSavePanel` and let the user select the output location. The `NSSavePanel` is actually displayed by the PowerBox and allows your app to break out of the sandbox to write to the file location that the user selects. You could configure the `NSSavePanel` to point to the location of the existing file, so that the user just needs to click **Save**.

I realise that this is not ideal because it breaks the nice drag/drop UI but at present it's the only supported way to write to a file outside the sandbox.

Comment: Thanks Rob. Sorry but I think ARC (OSX) **requires** a 64 bit target. About the Save dialog boxes, it simply won't work for my app. You drag a bunch of files from any location and it has no sense to ask user to confirm every movie. Thanks however for your useful info. I wonder if there is another way to update a movie file without having to rewrite it.

Comment: Yep, ARC requires 64-bit (technically it actually requires the modern runtime, which is is why it works in 32-bit on iOS but on the Mac the modern runtime is only available in 64-bit). My point was that QTKit will work in both 32- and 64-bit environments.